# The generalized formula for Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

For $p=1$, the Runge-Kutta is just the Euler method. I am just wondering if there exists a generalized formula for Runge-Kutta method when $p$ is arbitrary. Thanks!

---

[image]

Comment: Which Runge-Kutta methods? There are lots of them, among them the Euler methods. See https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/low-order-RK.pdf for some other examples.

Comment: Explicit Runge Kutta method.

Comment: I've attached a picture in the post. And I was talking about part c and d. Thanks!